# how to run rake db:migrate on irb

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to run a migration script on irb but it returns syntax error.

```
irb(main):008:0> rake db:migrate:up VERSION=20171006190045
SyntaxError: (irb):8: syntax error, unexpected tLABEL
rake db:migrate:up VERSION=20171006190045
```

tried `rake db:migrate:redo VERSION=20171006190045`

Also tried this

```
irb(main):012:0> require 'db/migrate/20171006190045_update_details.rb'
LoadError: cannot load such file -- db/migrate/20171006190045_update_details.rb
    from (irb):12
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rake` is not meant to be run within IRB. I agree with @spickermann. You can run it in rails console by using `system` command.

```
$ rails c
> system("rake db:migrate:up VERSION=20171006190045")
```

or simply in terminal

```
$ rake db:migrate:up VERSION=20171006190045
```

Comment: I like your solution. Didn't know you could use `system` to execute rake commands in the rails console. Good job!

Answer (score 1):

`rake` is not meant to be run within IRB. It is a command line program like IRB. Just exit IRB and run it in your terminal.

Answer (score 1):

`irb` does not respond to `rake`. Exit out of `irb` like so:

```
irb(main):008:0> exit
```

Then simply run your rake command:

```
rake db:migrate:up VERSION=20171006190045
```

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not necessary to run it using system command.

```
Rails.application.load_tasks
Rake::Task['my_task'].invoke
```